# How to use WP Theme Option: Custom_Backgrounds on specific element?

Tags: theme-options, theme-customizer, custom-background

I want to use the WP Theme option [Custom_Backgrounds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds) on a specific div.

By default it adds it to the body and I dont see a way of changing this.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your theme uses in-built `custom-background` callback then you can overwrite `add_theme_support` in your child theme. Yo do not need to use `remove_theme_support`.

First add `custom-background` support with your callback function.

```
$defaults_args = array(
    'wp-head-callback'       => 'my_custom_background_cb',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults_args );
```

In callback function specify `div` CSS class or  ID

```
function my_custom_background_cb() {
    $bg_image = get_background_image();

    if ( empty( $bg_image ) ) {
        return;
    } else { ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .your-div-class {
                background: url('<?php echo $bg_image; ?>') no-repeat;
            }
        </style><?php
    }
}
```

If theme printing CSS in header or using some other custom function (not using callback function) then you can remove body background image by CSS.